# Неожиданное поведение приватного члена

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В net.core в неизменяемых коллекциях, есть такой код:

```
public sealed partial class ImmutableList<T> : IImmutableList<T>, IList<T>, IList, IOrderedCollection<T>, IImmutableListQueries<T>, IStrongEnumerable<T, ImmutableList<T>.Enumerator>
{
        /// <summary>
        /// An empty immutable list.
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2104:DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes")]
        public static readonly ImmutableList<T> Empty = new ImmutableList<T>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The root node of the AVL tree that stores this set.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Node _root;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImmutableList{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        internal ImmutableList() => _root = Node.EmptyNode;
        //...
 }
```

как мы видим `_root` приватный, но есть такой код:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Builder"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">A list to act as the basis for a new list.</param>
internal Builder(ImmutableList<T> list)
{
    Requires.NotNull(list, nameof(list));
    _root = list._root;
    _immutable = list;
}
```

В конструкторе другого класса есть доступ к '_root', как такое возможно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс `Builder` [вложен в `ImmutableList<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray_1.Builder.cs).

```
namespace System.Collections.Immutable
{
    public partial struct ImmutableArray<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A writable array accessor that can be converted into an <see cref="ImmutableArray{T}"/>
        /// instance without allocating memory.
        /// </summary>
        [DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
        [DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(ImmutableArrayBuilderDebuggerProxy<>))]
        public sealed class Builder : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
        {

        }
    }
}
```

У вложенных (nested) классов есть полный доступ ко всем членам содержащих из классов, включая private и protected поля.

[Nested Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

> A nested type has access to all of the members that are accessible to its containing type. **It can access private and protected members of the containing type**, including any inherited protected members.